# JQuery: Iterate through all table rows and display popup for each cell with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Using JQuery, I am trying to iterate through all rows of a table and display a timed popup **for every cell that has the class** = "cell-which-triggers-popup".

The JQuery function below is only displaying a popup for the first cell found. How can I get it to display a popup for every cell with that class.

I have a working example here - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twobears/xaqtawog/490/)

HTML:

```
    <div id="popup" data-name="name" class="dialog" title="Bar Crossing Alert!">
    <p></p>            
</div>
<table id="1" border="1">
     <tr>
       <th>Trip ID</th>
       <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="cell-with-id">585</td>
       <td class="cell-which-triggers-popup">bar x</td>
    </tr>
         <tr>
       <td class="cell-with-id">444</td>
       <td class="closed">closed</td>
    </tr>
         <tr>
       <td class="cell-with-id">007</td>
       <td class="cell-which-triggers-popup">bar x</td>
    </tr>
         <tr>
       <td class="cell-with-id">987</td>
       <td class="open">open</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
      $("tbody tr td.cell-which-triggers-popup").each(function() {
   var cell_value = $(".cell-with-id").html();
              setInterval(function() {
        showPopup(cell_value)    
     }, 3000);
  });

    function showPopup(tr_id){
        $("#popup").dialog({
            width: 300,
            /*height: auto,*/
            resizable: false,
                show: 'blind',
                hide: 'blind',
            open: function(){
                $(this).find("p").html('At Least 10 minutes has expired.<br />Please check the status of the<br />current Bar Crossing.<br />Trip Report ID: ' + tr_id)
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the dialog is presenting the element with id="popup", and there's only one. If you want to pop up several dialogs, you'll need to create a new element each time:

```
var $dialog = $("#popup").clone();
$dialog.dialog( DIALOG_OPTIONS );
```

Comment: Hi Duncan - sort of works thank you. However is continually looping because of timer function. (see fiddle) and still only showing first row found. - http://jsfiddle.net/twobears/xaqtawog/491/

Comment: Changed to setTimeout and stopped the looping, but still only returning the first Trip ID. - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twobears/xaqtawog/492/)

Answer (score 0):

$(".cell-with-id") will select the first element from the matches. But what you need is the sibling td of the clicked element. Instead of using 'each' you can use a click event handler. And why do you need a setInterwel? This will trigger the showPopup in each 3000 ms. Even if user closes the popup it will reappear.

```
$("tbody tr td.cell-which-triggers-popup").click(function() {
      var cell_value = $(this).siblings(".cell-with-id").html();
        showPopup(cell_value)
```

});

working fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soumyasunny/akexpw0h/1/)

Comment: Trying to show a popup as reminder for the radio operator to check status of the boat that is crossing a dangerous bar after a set amount of time. Once boat is clear then radio operator can change status from 'cell-which-triggers-popup' to 'open' (which doesn't trigger popup)

Comment: you have to use 'clearInterval()' when the radio operator change status. Until then the same popup will show. How about showing two trip Id in the same popup?

Comment: Each trip Id relates to a separate boat that may have left at a different time or is crossing a different bar, so they need to be separately timed and identified with their own popup. I am trying to have one popup, per boat, that appears at a specific time after their cell status is changed to the 'cell-which-triggers-popup'. @Duncan Thacker